# How to "proxy" a method in Java

Tags: java, reflection

First off, I'm not sure how to best word my solution so if I seem to be babbling at times then please consider this.

There is an interface in a library I wish to modify without touching the physical code,

```
public interface ProxiedPlayer {
    // .. other code
    public void setPermission(String permission, boolean state);
}
```

I have written a third party library for handling permissions and having to hook into my API to edit permissions may be a step some developers do not want to take. So I ask that when `setPermission` is called is it possible to have it invoke my invoke the appropriate method in my library that will handle permission setting **whilst** ignoring the pre-programmed code or not?

Here is the full [interface](http://ci.md-5.net/job/BungeeCord/ws/api/target/apidocs/index.html) I am attempting to proxy.

I have looked into the Java Proxy class <s>but it seems you need an instance of the object you're trying to proxy in the first place.</s> Given that the method can be called any time I do not believe this to be my solution *but will happily stand corrected.*

**I do not have control over instantiation of classes implementing the ProxiedPlayer interface.**

EDIT: Ignorant me, there several events that I can subscribe to where it is possible to get an instance of the player, would this be the appropriate place to attempt to proxy the method? One of these events is fired when a player joins the server and getting the instance of the player is possible.

Would the Proxy code need to be called for every instance of the ProxiedPlayer interface or is it possible to simply proxy every invocation of the method in an easier way?

My library is a plugin loaded after everything else that is essential has finished loading.

**Edit #2:**

```
import net.md_5.bungee.api.connection.ProxiedPlayer;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class InvocationProxy implements InvocationHandler {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        ProxiedPlayer player = (ProxiedPlayer) proxy;
        if(method.getName().equals("setPermission")) {
            // Call my code here?
        }
        return method.invoke(player, args);
    }
}
```

Would something along the lines of what I have above work or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Comment: Where are instances of classes that implement `ProxiedPlayer` instantiated and used? Is it entirely in your library? From your last paragraph, it sounds like you have no control over the implementations or when they are created - if so, I think it would be difficult to achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: @andersschuller I have updated my question to include more information, like I said I'm not sure how to word it - my bad!

Comment: ClassLoader?? You may write custom class loader which will load your Class that implements setPermission first? This way, your class's method would be executed?

Comment: Unfamiliar with ClassLoader as I've never really had to use them, will look into it though! Would it matter that I do not control instantiation of the class implementing ProxiedPlayer?

Comment: Don't think that matters, Class loader is just looking for the first place where needed resource is located. It means that if class with the same name and package appears in 2 jars the first found will be used, for example!!

Comment: If you have no control over when and how the class is instantiated then you're looking at AspectJ AOP with either compile-time preprocessing or the load-time weaving agent.

Comment: @AADTechnical you say the first found will be used, but my JAR file is a plugin activated by the server after everything has loaded

Comment: ya, that is how I am controlling which class to be used when same class is packed in more than 2 jars..sorry if it does not apply to your situation!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to touch the original source, then you only solve this problem by using a Java agent that redefines any class that implements the `ProxiedPlayer` interface to enforce your security check before calling the actual method. AspectJ together with a load-time-weaving agent was already mentioned as a possible solution for this but you can also implement a pure Java solution using my library [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy):

```
public class InterceptionAgent {
  public static void premain(String arguments, 
                             Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .rebase(isSubtypeOf(ProxiedPlayer.class))
      .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
        @Override
        public DynamicType.Builder transform(DynamicType.Builder builder) {
          return builder.method(named("setPermission"))
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyInterceptor.class)
                      .andThen(SuperMethodInvocation.INSTANCE));
        }
      }).installOn(instrumentation);
  }
}
```

With this agent, you more or less specify that you want to redefine any class that is a subtype of `ProxiedPlayer` to redefine (any) method named `setPermisson` in order to call a `MyInterceptor` (that would be your code) and to subsequently call the original implementation.

Note that the suggested implementation assumes that all classes implementing `ProxiedPlayer` implement the method of this interface and that there is only a single method of this signature. This might be too simple but it shows what direction to go.

Comment: Thankyou, this definitely does what I'm looking for and the library seems to be absolutely amazing after having playing around with it for a little while! The only thing I'm unsure of now is where do I call the premain method?

Comment: You do not call the premain method, the JVM does that for you. All you need to do is to define an *Agent jar* that you add to the Java application on startup, similar to adding something to the class path: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

Comment: thankyou for your help so far, where you have the MyInterceptor.class would the method have to be static or not and would it accept the original parameters or an instance of ProxiedPlayer + the original parameters? I tried a few examples which _should_ have logged the permission to System.out, but nothing happened no matter how I tried

Comment: Can you post some code? Either on the mailing list or as a seperate question.

Comment: What if I do not have the ability to define a premain method, nor run an agent class? What are the options then?

Comment: There's *byte-buddy-agent* as a project that amplifies dynamic attach. Note however that this feature might go away in the future.